# ASP.NET MVC Ajax and the CKEditor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, ckeditor

I am working with MVC 1, and the CKEditor. I am integrating ajax forms which work great, but the editor window disappears after the ajax post. In webforms, I would have to not use ajax, or use a postback trigger. Is there a way to reload the editor on the ajax submission?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That sound weird, if its AJAX the editor must stay still, because its not a full page post. Are you using any included methods to get the editor content and Post it with ajax?.

Comment: No I am not doing anything with the editor. The editor is generated on window.onload, so it is not regenerated on the Ajax submission.

Comment: What are you using to submit the ajax post?

Comment: Using the mvc ajax.beginform() with a regular input button

Comment: Anyone working with this out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to good solution other than to reload the page, not ideal but works.

Answer (score -1):

use ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript to execute javascript via AJAX postback

Comment: MVC, not webforms. Not using Microsoft Ajax.